# How can I set the height of my first UITableViewCell higher than the others?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying this in my `viewDidLoad()`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 300.0
    }
    return 100.0
}
```

but this has no effect

Comment: That's not `viewDidLoad`. What do you mean? Is the above method inside `viewDidLoad`? If so, why?

Comment: `heightForRowAt indexPath ` delegate method of `UITableView` this is not related to `viewDidLoad`

Comment: heightForRowAt is write outside of viewdidLoad

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3 Write code in following way
Height for row is a tableView delegate method so you do. not write inside of ViewDidLoad method, you can write in outside of viewDidLoad method

import UIKit

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController,ProfileViewControllerDelegate {

    //MARK: - Outlet -

    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!

    //MARK: - View Life Cycle -
    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }

    //MARK: TablView Delegate
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return 300.0
        }
        return 100.0
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is the example of simple tableView which first row height is 300 and other's 100.

```
    import UIKit
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self
        }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 5
        }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


            let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID") as UITableViewCell!


            cell.textLabel?.text = "testing"

            return cell
        }

        // method to run when table view cell is tapped
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
        }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 300.0
    }
    return 100.0
}
```

}